# phantomjs: What does it mean when status is not populated?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

```
var page = require('webpage').create(); 

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log('Inner log: ' + msg);
};

var url = "http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html";
page.open(url, function() {
    console.log("status ",status);
    var props = page.evaluate(function() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('xref');
        for (var i=0;i<x.length;++i) {
            console.log(x[i].innerText);
        }
        ...
```

output:

```
❯ phantomjs css21_parser.js                                      
2013-03-17 03:27:01.737 phantomjs[95167:707] *** WARNING: Method userSpaceScaleFactor in class NSView is deprecated on 10.7 and later. It should not be used in new applications. Use convertRectToBacking: instead.
status
Inner log: 'azimuth'
Inner log: 'background-attachment'
Inner log: 'background-color'
Inner log: 'background-image'
Inner log: 'background-position'
Inner log: 'background-repeat'
....
```

Basically, the examples and API documentation state that success should be checked against "success" but in this case here it appears to be empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this will resolve your issue, but have you tried join the strings together, rather than comma separate?

`console.log("status " + status);`

EDIT:

I've just noticed your issue. You're not passing the `status` variable through, in the callback.

Your callback function should look like this:

`page.open(url, function(status) {`

Comment: Oh I didn't realize the status was the argument. Thanks